# rails deployment using capistrano & torquebox error 502

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, torquebox

I'm running a rails app using JRuby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) with Torquebox and trying to deploy to Digital ocean VPS, when I run 'cap deploy' everything runs perfectly fine, however when i try to go to visit the site i still see "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.1.19

This is my deploy.rb file

```
    `require 'torquebox-capistrano-support'
     require 'bundler/capistrano'



     # SCM
     # Update this part to match your server and location of your application code.
     server       "000.000.00.000", :web, :app, :primary => true
     set :repository, 'git@github.com:jrgrammont/EmployToy.git'
     set :branch,            "master"
     set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
     set :user,              "torquebox"
     set :scm,               :git
     set :scm_verbose,       true
     set :use_sudo,          false

     set :deploy_to, '/opt/apps/employtoy.com'
     set :torquebox_home,    "/opt/torquebox/current"
     set :jboss_init_script, "/etc/init.d/jboss-as-standalone"
     set :rails_env, 'development'
     set :app_context,       "/"
     set :app_ruby_version, '1.9'
     set :application, 'employtoy.com'

     default_environment['JRUBY_OPTS'] = '--1.9'
     default_environment['PATH'] =         '/opt/torquebox/current/jboss/bin:/opt/torquebox/current/jruby/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-  3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin'

     after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:assets:precompile'
     after 'deploy:update', 'deploy:resymlink', 'deploy:nginx'
     before 'deploy:finalize_update', 'deploy:assets:symlink'

     default_run_options[:pty] = true  # Must be set for the password prompt from git to   work
     set :deploy_via, :remote_cache


     namespace :deploy do
       desc "relink db directory"
        #if you use sqlite
        task :resymlink, :roles => :app do
        run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/db; rm -rf #{current_path}/db && ln -s # {shared_path}/db #{current_path}/db && chown -R torquebox:torquebox  #{current_path}/db"
        end


     # This is a weird part. I've found that asset complation with JRuby can really hog up  the memory, which can cause the application to crash
     # when doing a deploy. So, I like to compile the assets locally and SCP them to the server instead.
     # Just make sure you've commented out the load deploy/assets in your Capfile.
     namespace :assets do
     # If you want to force the compilation of assets, just set the ENV['COMPILE_ASSETS']
       task :precompile, :roles => :web do
       force_compile = ENV['COMPILE_ASSETS']
        begin # on first deploys, there is no current_revision so an error gets raised. in  this case we want to just compile assets and upload them.
       from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
       rescue
       force_compile = true
      end
        if ( force_compile) or (capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)}  vendor/assets/ lib/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0 )
       run_locally("rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile")
       run_locally "cd public && tar -jcf assets.tar.bz2 assets"
       top.upload "public/assets.tar.bz2", "#{shared_path}", :via => :scp
       run "cd #{shared_path} && tar -jxf assets.tar.bz2 && rm assets.tar.bz2"
       run_locally "rm public/assets.tar.bz2"
       run_locally("rake assets:clean")
     else
      logger.info "Skipping asset precompilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end

      task :symlink, roles: :web do
      run ("rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/assets &&
           mkdir -p #{latest_release}/public &&
           mkdir -p #{shared_path}/assets &&
           ln -s #{shared_path}/assets #{latest_release}/public/assets")
      end



      end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the tutorial again...not really sure, but it looks like Capistrano is not starting Torquebox.

Try ssh'ing into the box and starting it with:
sudo service jboss-as-standalone start

also look at the torquebox log at /var/log/jboss-as/console.log .. is that throwing any errors?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, i appreciate it! After ssh'ing into my server and ran what you suggested the nginx page did dissapear however the following message now shows, HTTP status 500 
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (InjectionError) Invalid injection - transaction-manager
 org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doRack(RackFilter.java:117)
 org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:101)
 org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:72)
 org.torquebox.web.servlet.SendfileFilter.doFilter(SendfileFilter.java:49)

Comment: Hi, 

Ha...well so much for "easy deployments" that were promised...

Yeah, JRuby, Torquebox, and Neo4j.rb all had updates since I wrote that blog post.  I updated the Chef recipe https://github.com/cfitz/neo4j-torquebox-kitchen . I also updated the demo app's gem file ( https://github.com/cfitz/neo4j-demo-app/blob/master/Gemfile ) and the Gemfile.lock to lock things down to the proper gem versions. And, on the first deploy you'll have to run
"service jboss-as-standalone restart" ( or start if it's not running) as root, for some reason...

Does that work?

Comment: Hi, Yea i know lol...so i've updated and used the latest torquebox files, this time after starting torquebox i only get We're sorry but something went wrong msg to check the app logs. When i check the logs i dont's see any errors except 2 warnings: 
1.                             
AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal

2.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015884: No security realm defined for http management service; all access will be unrestricted.

Comment: Also i am using rails 4, neo4j 2.3.0, neo4j-community 1.9, neo4j-advanced 1.9 and neo4j enterprise 1.9. when i run everything locally it works with no bundler issues. not sure what else i can do.